# Targeting Elements by Index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can accomplish this same thing with fewer functions, but I just can't figure out how to specifically target the #twitter, #facebook and #mail divs by index like I did with the #carrier divs. Here's the JS:

```
$('div.fb, div.tw, div.mail, div.tmobile, div.att, div.verizon, div.unlocked').click(function(){
    var clicked = $(this);
    var index = $(this).closest('div').index();
    $('#test-wrapper').fadeIn('fast', function(){
        if (clicked.hasClass('tmobile') || clicked.hasClass('att') || clicked.hasClass('verizon') || clicked.hasClass('unlocked')) {
            $('#carrier div').not(".close").eq(index).animate({"top": "+=524px"}, 500, function(){
                $(this).animate({"top": "-=24px"}, 200);
            });
        } else if (clicked.hasClass('mail')){
            $('#mail').animate({"top": "+=255px"}, 500, function(){
                $(this).animate({"top": "-=20px"}, 200);
            });
        } else if (clicked.hasClass('tw')){
            $('#twitter').animate({"top": "+=102px"}, 500, function(){
                $(this).animate({"top": "-=20px"}, 200);
            });
        } else {
            $('#facebook').animate({"top": "+=345px"}, 500, function(){
                $(this).animate({"top": "-=20px"}, 200);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yT9yg/ (don't worry about the missing images - they're stored locally for now - or the formatting, as I haven't done any media queries yet.)

Comment: What's wrong with `$('#mail').index()`? They're siblings, right? Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean.

Comment: I'm just trying to slim down the code. I want to combine everything here into one if and one else.

Comment: All those lists of classes bother me. You should give the elements another class that they all share, and target just that in your selectors.

Comment: And instead of using `index`, give each element a `data-target="someID"` attribute, and use this to find the element to animate. That will allow you to combine everything into one.

Comment: @barmar: yeah, I agree about all the classes. They're mostly just there because I wanted the option to style them differently in CSS if need be. Is there a special way to target an element with a data-target property in JQuery? Also, I'm sure you noticed my use of the code you helped me out with last time :)

Comment: Just did a quick search. Would I target it with .data()? I.e. $('div').data('dataTargetID').

Comment: You can give them multiple classes. Give them unique classes for styling, and a common class for selecting in jQuery. For using data, you would do `$('#'+$(this).data('targetID')).animate(...)`.